# How to Fix Dropdown Button Text Alignment Issue?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

I have created two dropdown buttons in my Flutter app, and I want them to look the same. Problem the text inside the hint of the second dropdown button is not showing correctly, creating a visual difference. How can I make sure the text in the second dropdown button aligns properly and looks like the first one?

[image: I]

First DropDownButton Widget Code:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                            isExpanded: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hoverColor: Colors.green,
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey4,
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                              ),
                            ),
                            hint: Text(
                              'İşlem Yapılan Hisse Sayısı',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: (buildJosefinSans(0.5, 16)),
                            ),
                            items: list
                                .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: item.toString(),
                                      child: Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        child: Text(
                                          item.toString(),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ))
                                .toList(),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null) {
                                return 'İşlem Yapılan Hisse Sayısı';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onChanged: (value) {
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              selectedValue = value.toString();
                            },
                            buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                            ),
                            iconStyleData: const IconStyleData(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_sharp,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              iconSize: 32,
                            ),
                            dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: CupertinoColors.systemGrey5,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                            ),
                            menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                            ),
                          )
```

Second DropDownButton Widget Code:

```
DropdownButtonFormField2<int>(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hoverColor: Colors.green,
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey4,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                          ),
                          isDense: true,
                        ),
                        value: buyDropDownValue,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_sharp,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 32,
                          ),
                        elevation: 16,
                        style: (buildJosefinSans(0.5, 16)),
                        onChanged: (int? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            buyDropDownValue = value!;
                            bDropDownValue = buyDropDownValue!;
                          });
                        },
                        hint: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(phoneWidth * 0.05, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Satın Alınan Hisse Sayısı', 
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: buildJosefinSans(0.5, 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                        items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value.toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        dropdownColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey5,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      )
```

Comment: the first dropdown is not using " isDense: true"? if you want to make the same for both I guest set the property isDense to false or to true for both dropdown.

Comment: I tried it but there was no difference. I don't know why the second text is not fitting inside the button exactly like first text.

Comment: look at your contentPadding is also difference.

Comment: Can you try to run those both of codes because there will be no difference second dropdown button text area size is bigger than the first one. No idea what is the problem. Also there is another difference, second dropdown button text has a padding because it's not fitting in the button exactly how it should be normally .

Comment: well, I had tried bro but the code is not full, it is not even compiling.

Comment: you are right, I didnt sent the couple of codes . Even now it's too long to check it. I thought those are the main parts that caused problem.

Comment: Change the content padding in DropdownButtonFormField2 to EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12).